# Could not start openssh server , not known host name on Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Ubuntu box that I wish to remote into. I installed openssh-server on my ubuntubox and start the service with sudo systemctl restart ssh.

When I check with the ssh status on server end, I got return :
ssh: Could not resolve hostname status: Name or service not known

I proceed to troubleshoot it with sshd - t ( test mode of ssh deamon)
The return came back as :
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

I then tried to reinstall the package by sudo apt-get purge openssh-sever, and also tried to regenerate host key by ssh-keygen -A

Nevertheless, none of them seems to fix the problem. Can anyone kindly provide some suggestion ?

One note is that my linux server use wifi to connect to local network, I am not sure if that would matter.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], [sf], or [su].

Comment: Once you've resolved your hostname issue (try `ping the.host.name` and get that working first), try `sudo apt purge openssh-server && sudo rm -rf /etc/ssh && sudo apt install openssh-server` to be sure you don't have odd permissions anywhere. Otherwise, try [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I will move my question over there. I also noticed yesterday that even my ssh status does not resolve hostname, I was able to login my ssh surprisingly.